# How to connect the idea of inner product, outer product, matrix element in 3 level composite system?

Tags: quantum-optics

I was solving steady state solution given by Lindblad equation, and I got stuck on the calculation part like what will be the value of $\langle e, 0|b, 0\rangle$?

And how should I rewrite $|d, 0\rangle\langle e, 0| \rho |e, 0\rangle\langle d, 0|$,
where, $\rho$ is a density matrix.

The possible transition is given in the attached image

Also, you can look into [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.14157) article I am referring to.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From (13) in the paper it looks as though the first two states you mention are orthogonal. Some more details about your confusion would definitely be appreciated

Comment: I don't quite see the relation between the title of the question and its body. Could you clarify what exactly you are asking?

Comment: On the appendix section of the attached paper, how should I compute the operator acting on dissipator?

Comment: One may refer to equation 14, A2 and A3.